# syslog is working but SysLogHandler is not

Tags: python, logging, syslog, uwsgi

I can't make SysLogHandler to work and it's driving me nuts.

This is my code:

```
   import logging
   import logging.handlers

   logger = logging.getLogger()
   sh = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(address='/dev/log/', facility='local1')
   logger.addHandler(sh)

   logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
   logger.info('Test')
```

And doesn't work. I have set local1 to output in `/var/log/test.log` in my syslog.conf and nothing appears, however if I use syslog it's working as expected:

```
   import syslog

   syslog.syslog(syslog.LOG_LOCAL1, 'Test from syslog')
```

I am on Debian 6, in an app served trough uwsgi.

Can you help me?

Comment: Where did you place this code? It should be the very first code to be executed in your app.

Comment: @Tisho in a function called in `__main__` as first thing.

Answer (score 2):

The UNIX socket name (the address argument) should end with a filename, not a "/".  So it should be address='/dev/log' on linux, typically.

Answer (score 0):

You provided `local1` as a string, but the module expects a constant. Even the default value is `LOG_USER`, see http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.SysLogHandler

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you mean `logger.setLevel()` instead of `logger.setLever()`.

Also, why do you re-`import logging.handlers`?

Comment: Yes it's a typo, the code is correct.
And I am re-importing logging.handlers because without I get an AttributeError.